# Android + PhoneGap wont play a video inside IMG folder

Tags: android, jquery, html, video, cordova

I'm currently developing an HTML app built with PhoneGap for Android that needs to play a video, the video container appears fine but there seems to be a problem with the "src" tag. I'm putting my video inside of my `img` directory, and call it as usual:

```
<video width="800" height="550" controls="controls">
    <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I also (for testing purposes) download the video directly to my Tablet SDCard and call it in the tag with and absolute path like this:

```
<video width="800" height="550" controls="controls">
    <source src="file:///sdcard/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

And this actually PLAYS just fine, so the problem seems to be when trying to play the video within the app's `www` directory... I've also checked the path and it seems to be fine, my .html is in the WWW directory so it should be just "img/video.mp4". My images in the app are being loaded just fine using the same path so I'm not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: I've had a similar issue with a native Android app ... could play video from the "raw" folder but if I wanted it in assets I had to copy it to the SD card before I could play it

Answer (score 0):

src must be like this in order to access into your www folder:
`src="/android_asset/www/MYFILE.mp4";`

Answer (score -1):

I too facing the same problem. when I give `src="/android_asset/www/video.mp4"` it appends `"file://"` to src and makes it `src="file:///android_asset/www/video.mp4"` and the video doesn't play. Is there any other way to this ?